# Change colors for values in pandas column list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hello everyone I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'list_text': [['t4', 't5', 't6'], ['t7', 't1', 't2', 't3']],
    'list_userid': [['u1', 'u2', 'u4'], ['u3']],
    'list_date': [['2021-01', '2021-02'], ['2021-01']]
})
```

and I want to change the color in the `list_text` column for each value. That is, the first value is red, then blue, etc. and everything is in the list and so for each row.
Is this even possible to do?

For example something like this:

[image]

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to generate yourself the HTML, then convert [`to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) without escaping:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

colors = ['#9FE2BF', '#DE3163', '#FFBF00', '#6495ED']

display(HTML(
  df.assign(list_text=['['+', '.join([f'<span style="color:{c}";>{v}</span>'
                                     for c, v in zip(colors, l)])+']'
                       for l in df['list_text']]
            )
    .to_html(escape=False)
))
```

*NB. note that [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) stops with the shortest iterable, ensure to have enough colors in `colors`. Alternatively, use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with a default color.*

Output:

[image: pandas Series of list with different color for each word]

##### edit

You actually don't need to make the string representation of list yourself, a list of HTML strings also works:

```
display(HTML(
  df.assign(list_text=[[f'<span style="color:{c}";>{v}</span>'
                                     for c, v in zip(colors, l)]
                       for l in df['list_text']]
            )
    .to_html(escape=False)
))
```

Comment: I don't really understand what is  itertools. zip_longest

Comment: This is an alternative to `zip` that handles iterables of different length. Try for example `list(zip([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]))` and `list(zip_longest([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], fillvalue=0))` to see the difference